# Cant arrange array items in ascending order in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Im trying to arrange some numbers in ascending order in JS, but it doesnt seem to work and I get the following console log : [ 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 18, 18, 24, 36, 72 ]

Here is the code :

```
var firstNum = 18;
var secondNum = 72;
var array = [];
var otherArray = [];

for (i = 0; i <= firstNum; i++) {
    if(firstNum % i === 0) {
        array.push(i);
    }
}

for (j = 0; j <= secondNum; j++) {
    if(secondNum % j ===0) {
        array.push(j);
    }
}

for (k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
    if(array[k] > array[k+1]) {
        var temp = array[k];
        array[k] = array[k+1];
        array[k+1] = temp;
        }
    }


console.log(array)
console.log(otherArray)
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: why are first and second num?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: what does it do? or should do?

Comment: I see that you trying to sort array using traditional sorting algorithm. But, I don't understand the algorithm that you are using for sorting:(

Comment: It should put the numbers that respect the if statement in the array

Comment: Im using bubble sort as the algorithm

Comment: @TudorApostol Bubble sort includes nested loops. Where is nested loop in your code?

Comment: Doesn't bubble sort use 2 for loops

Comment: First result from google: http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/07/09/friday-algorithms-javascript-bubble-sort/

Comment: Should `array` variable be not empty?

Comment: Using `array[k+1]` and `k<array.length` you are going out of bounds.

Comment: So, the final point is, you don't have to implement traditional sorting algorithm in javascript. Instead you can use existing sort method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Yeah, you're right krisph, that was my bad. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the code like this :

```
for (i = 0; i <= arrayX.length-1; i++)
  {
    if (arrayX[i] > arrayX[i+1])
      {
        temp = arrayX[i+1];
        arrayX[i+1] = arrayX[i];
        arrayX[i] = temp;
        i = i-2;
      }
  }
```

```js
var firstNum = 18;
var secondNum = 72;
var array = [];
var otherArray = [];

for (i = 0; i <= firstNum; i++) {
  if (firstNum % i === 0) {
    array.push(i);
  }
}

for (j = 0; j <= secondNum; j++) {
  if (secondNum % j === 0) {
    array.push(j);
  }
}

for (i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
  if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
    temp = array[i + 1];
    array[i + 1] = array[i];
    array[i] = temp;
    i = i - 2;
  }
}
alert(array)
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Sure? What happens if array[0] > array[1]?

Answer (score 0):

```
Use otherArray also like
for (j = 0; j <= secondNum; j++) {
    if(secondNum % j ==0) {
        otherArray.push(j);

    }
}
then print by using the same logic of temp it will give individual array output in ascending order and if you want to join two array output then use concat/merge and then print
```